# Why aren't my controllers actions accessible with unit tests in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have set up my route as such:

`Route::controller('clients', 'Controllers\ClientsController');`

Through this method I can easily access all the controller functions via post and get.  However I cannot test them as easily.

```
public function testCantDeleteOtherAccountsClient()
{

    Route::enableFilters();

    $user = Models\User::find(1);

    $this->be($user);

    $response = $this->action('GET', 'ClientsController@getDelete');

    $this->assertRedirectedToAction('ClientsController@getIndex');

}
```

This test results in the message

> InvalidArgumentException: Route [ClientsController@getDelete] not defined.

The method accessible via url though.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this out myself (a route specified via the controller) your issue is that using `action` requires a named route. Controller routes do not currently support this as far as I'm aware of.

If you create a test route:

```
Route::get('test', array(
    'as' => 'testName', 
    'uses' => 'ClientsController@getDelete'
));
```

And try

```
$this->action('GET', 'testName');
```

The test should pass, you can view all the routes with names via `php artisan routes`.

You may want to use `$this->client->request()` instead. You can check if a redirect occurred with:

```
$this->assertRedirectedTo("some\url");
```

Note that `$this->call()` is just an alias to `$this->client->request()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found changing it to use call instead of action worked for me:

`$response = $this->call('GET', 'clients/delete/1');`